# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

For some dumb reason, I am using Discord.JS v13. And ever since I have been getting these weird errors that I had no idea exists. Every time I run the command it just gives an error and shuts down the bot. I tried adding the try and catch but those dont work for v13 anymore I dont think. Here is my code if you guys can help.

The error is at line 32 btw

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const https = require('https')
const url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/catpics/hot/.json?limit=300'
module.exports = {
    name: "cat",
    description: "meow",
     execute(message, args, client) {
        message.reply("I am loading the image, if it does not come up try again later due to errors.")
        https.get(url, (result) => {
            var body = ''
            result.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk
            })

            result.on('end', () => {
                var response = JSON.parse(body)
                var index = response.data.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1].data

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {

                    var text = index.selftext
                    const textembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("cute")
                        .setColor(9384170)
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send({embeds: [textembed]})
                }

                var image = index.preview.image[0].source.url.replace('&amp;', '&')
                var title = index.title
                var link = 'https://reddit.com' + index.permalink
                var subRedditName = index.subreddit_name_prefixed

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {
                    const textembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle("cute")
                        .setColor(9384170)
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send({embeds: [textembed]})
                }
                console.log(image);
                const imageembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("cute")
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setColor(9384170)
                    .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})`)
                    .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)
                message.channel.send({embeds: [imageembed]})
            }).on('error', function (e) {
                console.log('Got an error: ', e)
            })
        })

     }
}
```

Output:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

Comment: Of course, you made sure that `index`, `index.preview` and `index.preview.image` exist, right? Try logging them before trying to access `index.preview.image[0]`, you might have your answer.

Comment: It won't let me log them, it just sends the error and then everything crashes

Comment: Do you have a way to log it?

Comment: If i log the index, index.preview or index.preview.image the console gets an error and says this: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')

Comment: Then it means exactly what it says: `There is no key named "preview" in the variable you are logging (index)`. `Trying to read "image" from a key that is undefined`. Even `index` might be undefined.

Comment: How can I define it?

Comment: Um we can't answer that,Honestly we don't have a clue how the code words and what does it do and what even is `index`,   its your code and you should know how to define a variable

Comment: I am writing an full answer as of now, please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm guessing you have no background on programmation, I'm gonna go over every part of the code you probably copy-pasted from an example and/or adapted to your needs and try to explain in-depth what behavior you should adopt when any error comes. I'll stop once we reach the line of the error, `line 32`.

Keep in mind that it is not the place but I'm gonna do it as a one-time thing. The appropriate place would be [Stack Exchange's Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

First, given the `url` and the presence of `https` module, I assume you try to retrieve informations about pictures of cats from Reddit.

Let's dive directly where there's code to discuss. The `result.on('end')` function will be executed when there is no more body to parse, but I think you got that.

Then, you try to retrieve data about a particular image, chosen at random:

```
var index = response.data.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1].data
```

Two things from here:

- [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) only returns a number between `0` and `1`, making this whole line chosing a number between 1 and 100. You then miss the opportunity to chose the element 0, since Arrays in JS are zero-based indexed. Also, you can reduce the limit in your Reddit URL from 300 to 100.
- You assume 2 things: that `children` is indeed a key of the `response` Reddit sent you back, AND that the `children` array goes up to 100 elements.

What happens if `children` array has only, say 15 elements (if it exists at all)? You will have another error. I'll leave it to you to come up with a solution to check both things.

There:

```
var image = index.preview.image[0].source.url.replace('&amp;', '&')
```

you once again **assume** that `preview`, `image` (as an array), `source`, and `url` exist.

Now I've gone ahead and copy-pasted the result of the URL `https://www.reddit.com/r/catpics/hot/.json?limit=100` in a [JSON Beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer), and it happens that the `preview` you're asking on line 32 exists, however, `image` don't.

You only forgot an `s`, since `images` exists under `preview`.

In fact, your error comes down to two things:

1. The variable `index` might be undefined because you might try to access `response.data.children` array with an unreachable index (e.g `response.data.children` has only 15 elements and your Math.random gives you 55)
2. `image` field doesn't exist in `preview`, only `images` do.

Finally, to illustrate the `TypeError` you got, it is like asking someone to read you a completely blank paper, or giving an essay to a blind person and telling him to read it for you.

Either way, before asking a question on here, you should try a little harder. You could have figured it out yourself if you tried to log in between each line until narrowing down the error.

Also, if these are `weird errors that I had no idea exists`, then you're not really ready to code yet. I get these `TypeError` a half-dozen times a day if not more. That may sound harsh but you can't come and ask for help for any minor inconvenience you come across, or else you won't learn anything. Not to mention you didn't post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

With all that said, I stay available in the comments if the two things I mentioned you should fix don't solve the issue.

---

Following the comments on this answer, I'll add more details. I'll go through how to resolve the issue as well, so OP can apply similar thinking and procedures for other problems.

If you go on [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/catpics/hot/), which is the URL present on your code, only not in JSON form, you will see that there are posts that you want to exclude. Typically, I don't think the posts from `TrendingBot` are interesting, so you can just exclude them. That is why you were having `/r/catpics enters TOP 5000 subreddits`. Anything that has `index.author === 'TrendingBot'` is no bueno.

For the others matters, you can inspect keys and values via a JSON beautifier (that I linked above).

Looking at the JSON beautified myself, I don't think you're searching for the right key regarding the `image`. The image you probably want to display is the image under the `index.url` key, which is the image of the actual post. I really don't think `preview` is what you should be searching for.

Finally, for the link, again, I don't think you're searching for the right key. I think you should grab `index.permalink` instead of `index.subreddit_name_prefixed`.

Your final message should look something like this:

```
const image = index.url.replace('&amp;', '&');
const title = index.title;
const link = 'https://reddit.com' + index.permalink;
const subRedditName = index.subreddit_name_prefixed;

const imageembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("cute")
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setColor(9384170)
                    .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})`)
                    .setURL(link);
```

Comment: I fixed the errors thanks to you, but now it just sends this? https://ibb.co/Cvr5DwW Is there a way to not send "top 5000" or whatever?

Comment: If I click it it takes me to a comment link, why is it comments when I didnt add comment sections to the url?

Comment: Still keeps saying TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images') also

Comment: Please give me minutes to edit my original answer.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') This is the new error, is like my NodeJS outdated?? (line 32 again)

Comment: I've updated my answer, see below the horizontal line.

Comment: Still says TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') even though the line doesnt have source???

Comment: It either comes from another file where you have the `source` or NodeJS bugged and you need to re-launch `npm start`. If you replaced your original `line 32` with mine, then it is **impossible** that "reading (source)" comes again.

Comment: Yeah its fixed I didnt press save somehow

Comment: Thank you sooo much